# READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE error in Cordova Plugin

Tags: android, android-studio, cordova, cordova-plugins, android-permissions

I'm making a Cordova plugin that controls all phone calls. First, I did it in Android Studio and when it worked correctly I moved it to the plugin.

The problem is that the `READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE` error has appeared and I don't know how to resolve it. I have `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission granted, but the error continues.

Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: In Android 10 and above you can't have `READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE` as a "regular developer": [https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/device-identifiers](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/device-identifiers)

Comment: My app will not be published on the Play Store, so I can't fix it?